# How to sum two times with milliseconds?

Tags: php

Is there any way to sum two times with milliseconds like this:

```
00:01:02.73
00:03:03.01
```

to one?

the result should be like this:

```
00:04:05.74
```

format is simple "`hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds`"

If yes, how?

Comment: turn both in miliseconds and add, then format it back?

Comment: You should take a look at `microtime()`

Comment: what kind of time is this anyways?

Comment: well it is like counting laps time

Comment: @taesu: So it sounds like duration.  One lap around the track took `h:m:s.u`

Comment: it's really is duration... sorry for my not so good english skills :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I wrote few functions which is helping me to do that

```
$time1 = "00:15:45.89";
$time2 = "00:18:30.22";

$milli1 = timeToMilliseconds($time1);
$milli2 = timeToMilliseconds($time2);

$new = $milli1 + $milli2;

$time = formatMilliseconds($new);
echo $time;

function timeToMilliseconds($time){
    $time_start = substr($time, -11, -3);
    $time_end = substr($time, -3);

    $time_arr = explode(':', $time_start);
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach($time_arr as $key => $val){
        if($key == 0){
            $seconds += $val * 60 * 60;
        }elseif($key == 1){
            $seconds += $val * 60;
        }elseif($key == 2){
            $seconds += $val;
        }
    }

    $seconds = $seconds.$time_end;
    $milliseconds = $seconds * 1000;

    return $milliseconds;
}

function formatMilliseconds($milliseconds) {
    $seconds = floor($milliseconds / 1000);
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $milliseconds = $milliseconds % 1000;
    $seconds = $seconds % 60;
    $minutes = $minutes % 60;

    $format = '%u:%02u:%02u.%03u';
    $time = sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $milliseconds);
    return rtrim($time, '0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has a problem with your solution @Scorpioniz, when the time is "**1:34:55.831**" for example, the return from formatMilliseconds is "**1582:10:31.704**".

I made some changes in the **timeToMilliseconds** function and I think that is more consistent:

```
function timeToMilliseconds($time){
    $dateTime = new DateTime($time);

    $seconds = 0;
    $seconds += $dateTime->format('H') * 3600;
    $seconds += $dateTime->format('i') * 60;
    $seconds += $dateTime->format('s');

    $seconds = floatval($seconds . '.' . $dateTime->format('u'));

    return $seconds * 1000;
}
```

Or if your version of PHP is minor than 5.2.2 then you can do:

```
function timeToMilliseconds($time){
    sscanf($time, "%d:%d:%d.%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $microseconds);

    $seconds += $hours * 3600;
    $seconds += $minutes * 60;

    $seconds = floatval($seconds . '.' . $microseconds);

    return $seconds * 1000;
}
```

I hope someone enjoy.

*(Sorry for my English if I said something strange :P)*

Answer (score -2):

I've found this, it has less code than yours and it does the job. I've added function for milliseconds.
I'm wondering if php has something built-in for this.

```
/**
 * @author Masino Sinaga, http://www.openscriptsolution.com
 * @copyright October 13, 2009
 */


function sum_the_time($time1, $time2) {

    $times = array($time1, $time2);
    $seconds = 0;
    $Imiliseconds = 0.0;

    foreach ($times as $time){
        list($rest, $miliseconds) = explode('.', $time);
        $Imiliseconds += '0.'.$miliseconds;
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $rest);
        $seconds += $hour*3600;
        $seconds += $minute*60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }

    $seconds += floor($Imiliseconds);
    $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
    $seconds -= $hours*3600;
    $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
    $seconds -= $minutes*60;
    $miliseconds  = $Imiliseconds-floor($Imiliseconds);
    // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}:{$miliseconds}";
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $miliseconds); // Thanks to Patrick
}
echo sum_the_time($time, $time2);  // this will give you a result: 19:12:25
```

Comment: That will fail badly. consider `23:00:00` + `23:00:00` -> 1 day 2 hours -> formats out to 2 hours. You can NOT use time values as unix timestamps.

Comment: for me it would be good variant, if it would return me result, not 0... 
because for my this system it will never be more than few hours in sum of all times what i will be needed to sum